# Excel VBA with Advanced Filter "Error: Excel Ran out of resources"

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, advanced-filter

I have code in VBA that uses an Advanced filter to fill multiple tables. It worked without any errors before. I upgraded from Office 2013 to Office 365 and suddenly I get error messages on the code...

The Advanced filter runs, fills, and filters the tables correctly but I still get an error message that pops up **"Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result these formulas cannot be evaluated"**. If I press okay another error shows **"Run-time Error 1004: Advanced Filter method of range class failed"**. The file contains no formulas, 30500 rows, 37 columns.

**EDIT (added tried solutions)**

I've searched for solutions online and tried a couple but none have worked so far. I've tried the following:

- Closing down all Excel applications and run macro again
- closing down all application and only running Excel
- Reduce the core processors for Excel from 4 to 2
- Turn off the Multi-threaded calculation in Advanced
  options
- Remove all .COM add-ins
- Reduce the file to only use 100 rows and not the full file, tried 50 as well
- Tried manually using the advanced filter, which doesn't work anymore, I get the same error messages.
- I checked all the `On Error Resume Next` code. They are all enclosed and end with `GoTo 0`
- Tried removing filters on the extract datasheet and copy to range sheet
- Tried activating the sheet where I'm copying to first before running the filter
- Tried changing the filter criteria to a set range and not whole columns
  `Set CorpOrdCompCrit = .Range("$A$8:$F$10")`

I use advanced filter about 20 times in the code, so it's a bit of a problem. One section of the code looks like this (all 20 sections for the advanced filter are structured the same but with different filter criteria, sometimes just 1 filter):

```
'Create Filter Criteria ranges
With MainWB.Worksheets.Add
    .Name = "FltrCrit"
    Dim FltrCrit As Worksheet
    Set FltrCrit = MainWB.Worksheets("FltrCrit")
End With

With FltrCrit
    Dim CorpOrdCompCrit As Range
    Dim myLastColumn As Long

'Create Corporate Order Compliance Filter Criteria Range
    .Cells(7, "A") = "Corp Order Comp"
    .Cells(8, "A") = "MS"
    .Cells(9, "A") = "=4"
    .Cells(10, "A") = "=4"
    .Cells(8, "B") = "SOH"
    .Cells(9, "B") = "=0"
    .Cells(10, "B") = "=0"
    .Cells(8, "C") = "On Order"
    .Cells(9, "C") = "=0"
    .Cells(10, "C") = "=0"
    .Cells(8, "D") = "RP Type"
    .Cells(9, "D") = "Roster"
    .Cells(10, "D") = "Roster"
    .Cells(8, "E") = "Format"
    .Cells(9, "E") = "Corporate"
    .Cells(10, "E") = "Hyper"
    .Cells(8, "F") = "Region"
    .Cells(9, "F") = VRegion
    .Cells(10, "F") = VRegion

    
    'get last column, set range name
    With .Cells
        myLastColumn = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(8), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set CorpOrdCompCrit = .Range(.Cells(8, "A"), .Cells(10, myLastColumn))
    End With

'CORPORATE ORDER COMPLIANCE
Dim tblFiltered As ListObject
Dim copyToRng As Range, SDCRange As Range

Set tblFiltered = wb.Worksheets("Corporate Order Compliance").ListObjects("Table_Corporate_Order_Compliance3")

tblFiltered.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

Set SDCRange = wsSDC.ListObjects("Table_SDCdata").Range
Set copyToRng = tblFiltered.HeaderRowRange

'Use Advanced Filter
SDCRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=CorpOrdCompCrit, CopyToRange:=copyToRng, Unique:=False
```

the bottom part is where the error pop's up, on this line for the advanced filter.

```
'Use Advanced Filter
SDCRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=CorpOrdCompCrit, CopyToRange:=copyToRng, Unique:=False
```

Does anyone know why this is suddenly happening and how I can fix the problem, please?

Comment: This line should be `Set CorpOrdCompCrit = .Range(.Cells(8, "A"), .Cells(10, myLastColumn))` though I have no idea if that would cause this error.

Comment: @SJR I'm unfortunately still getting the same errors on the same line

Comment: What is the address of `CorpOrdCompCrit`?

Comment: @SJR it's showing `$A$8:$F$10`

Comment: Where and how do you define `SDCRange`? Have you tried doing this manually?

Comment: @SJR sorry I see I didn't add that section, I've edited my post to add it `Set SDCRange = wsSDC.ListObjects("Table_SDCdata").Range`. When I initially wrote the code I did it all manually to test and it worked. I then used the macro several times and it worked, but since upgrading, I got the error.

Comment: Googling suggests that this error message is not connected to the code per se, but to do with the size of the file/formulas. Don't know how much data you have, but try it on a small table and see if that causes the same problem. You might want to read some of the google suggestions.

Comment: @SJR the points I mentioned in my post came from some google suggestions, which unfortunately didn't help, but I did try a couple more just in case. Removing .COM add-ins; again selecting fewer core processors; I tried manually using the Advanced filter on just 100, then 50 lines. It didn't work but gave the same errors. Strange that with the macro it works but still stops and gives an error. I don't understand how it can work fine and then suddenly not. The data file is 30500 rows, 37 columns, no formulas in. I'll keep trying.